# Joomla3 component add additional registration fields

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, user-management, joomla-component

I am currently creating a shop-like component for Joomla 3. For this component, I will need some additional user-fields (Address) for the processing of the order.

My question is as follows:

What would in your opinion be the best way to achieve this:

1. Edit the Joomla Login component and add the required fields to the database
2. Use an other already existing component for user management
3. Implement an own registration part in my component and create the login-module myself

Which of these possibilities would you suggest and why? Or would you even choose an other solution, then tell me ;)

Comment: I think I just found my answer, since 1.6 you are able to create your own custom fields using the profile_plugin delivered with joomla see: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never edit core files or tables, doing so prevents you from being able to upgrade to the latest security releases without loosing all of your work, and constant security updates is one thing Joomla is very proactive about.
2. Looking at using [extended profiles](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin), but remember that other extension also include profile plugins.
3. Most existing e-commerce, community or social network extensions extend the base user details by using a second table where records are linked by the core user ID, this way they can extend as much as require while still retaining the benefits of Joomla upgrades and authentication mechanisms.
4. Typically in e-commerce solutions you only need the extended information when the user has filled their cart and are in the process of "checking out" this is a low impact point to ask the user for those extra details if you don't find them already stored by Joomla or your component.

Comment: Because the only location where these details will be used is the shop which I am creating myself, I made a little profile_plugin with these fields. That way, I won't be able to differ between delivery/payment address, but I don't want that.